# Как заменить два цикла лямбда выражением?

Tags: java, lambda

Как заменить следующие циклы на лямбды или может подскажите как сделать по другому , этот код

```
private Boolean ridesIntersect(List<Ride> firstListRides, List<Ride> secondListRides) {

    for (Ride rideRequest : firstListRides) {
      for (Ride rideFromTicket : secondListRides) {
        if (rideHasCommonStation(rideRequest, rideFromTicket)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Второй цикл :

```
for (RailwayCarriage carriage : carriages) {
      freeSeats.put(carriage.getNumber(), new ArrayList<>());
      for (int numberPlace = 1; numberPlace <= carriage.getAllCountPlace(); numberPlace++) {
        if (!placeIsBooked(carriage.getNumber(), numberPlace, bookedPlaces)) {
          freeSeats.get(carriage.getNumber()).add(numberPlace);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: `Как заменить следующие циклы на лямбды` - а чем циклы не устраивают? .................... `или может подскажите как сделать по другому , этот код` - хотелось бы знать что этот код должен делать в принципе, чтоб посоветовать

Comment: Сказали , что цикл в цикл плохая практика , первая функция ищет в двух списках общие элементы .

Comment: @flagmen цикл в цикле плохая практика, если можно обойтись одним циклом. Если это не возможно, то при переделке на стримы вы получите стрим в стриме. Вы можете это увидеть внизу у Вечеслава. Но ваш цикл читается намного легче, чем тот же код но в стримах.

Comment: Да, я не сказал бы что менять цикл на стрим это всегда хорошая практика, в-первую очередь от этого код должен стать проще для понимания, а "дерусь, потому что дерусь" (с) это не очень хорошо.

Comment: "Но ваш цикл читается намного легче, чем тот же код но в стримах" - зависит от практики, со временем привыкаешь и даже сложные стримы читаются легче циклов (особенно, при хорошем форматировании), но это уже про вкус фламастеров.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Как-то так:

```
return firstListRides.stream().anyMatch(
          rideRequest -> secondListRides.stream().anyMatch(
             rideFromTicket -> rideHasCommonStation(rideRequest,rideFromTicket)
          )
       );
```

2) Как-то так (я использовал некий `Pair<K,V>` - их много в гуавах/апачах, да самописных [это просто пара ключ-значение], но можно вместо него взять вообще `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` ):

```
return carriages.stream().map(
   carriage -> new Pair<>(
      carriage, 
      Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1)
            .limit(carriage.getAllCountPlace())
            .filter(numberPlace -> !placeIsBooked(
                 carriage.getNumber(), numberPlace, bookedPlaces))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
      )
  ).collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getKey, Pair::getValue))
```

**P.S.** Я бы не сказал, что лямбда всегда лучше (даже по производительности), не стоит менять цикл на лямбду, если код в результате для вас и большинства команды становится только сложнее.

Stream Api в первую очередь нужен, чтобы упростить понимание кода, производительность часто может быть даже хуже. Тем более не стоит делать головоломную лямбду, если с циклом все решается намного проще и понятнее.